# Build HTML dynamic table from .txt file using PHP

Tags: php, html, text, dynamic, html-table

I am trying to create a **html dynamic table** from **.txt file** which is updated regularly. The .txt data structure is something like this:

```
25/07/2020 13:45:22;1
25/07/2020 14:15:22;0
25/07/2020 17:44:20;1
```

The html table itself should have at least 4 columns (two of them hard coded):
**ID** | **NAME** | **TIME** (from .txt) | **STATE** (from .txt)

How can I accomplish this using **PHP**?
I can't use **fopen**.

Thanks!

Comment: can you use file_get_contents?

Comment: Yes @DCR. That's what I'm trying at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with three separate parts:

1. The File on the User side.

Plain HTML and JS - You just connect to a php-File on the Server via jQuery `ajax` to retrieve the Content of your .txt file:

```
let yourData;
function waitForMsg(){
//get your Data from the Server
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "getData.php",

        async: true, 
        cache: false,
        timeout:50000,

        success: function(data){ 
            yourData = (data);
            renderStuff(); 
            ractive.update();
            setTimeout(
                waitForMsg,
                15000
            );
        }
    });

};
```

2. a file on your Server

On your server you fetch the Data in getData.php:

```
<?php
$lines = file_get_contents("myData.txt"); //gives you the Data as Array for easier handling
echo ($lines);
?>
```

3. updating the data in the users view

I'd use ractive.js for rendering the data inside the html without reloading it, but there maybe a dozen other ways:

```
function renderStuff() {
    const template = "{{#Data}}<tr><td>harcoded</td><td>harcoded</td><td>{{date}}</td>{{time}}</td></tr>{{/Data}}";
    ractive = new Ractive({
        el: '#target',
        template: template,
        modifyArrays: true,
        data: {yourData},
        computed: {
            Data() {
                let tempdoc = this.get('kinderchen');
                for (let x of tempdoc) {
                    //do something with your Data to make it more readable. I'd assume building a JSON out of it
                    //so it's something like: [{'date':'12/12/12'}, {'time':'15:22'}, ...]
                }

                return tempdoc;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Of course this is a very shortened example and would need some changes to work, but it's a way to start.